# How can I distinguish a local picture and a cloud picture in Photos app?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, onedrive, photos

I'm using Windows 10 10.0.10586.318 and have the option to show pics from cloud and local on a duplicate way.

I like to this because I like to delete them from from but keep them on cloud.

The problem is that looks like it is impossible to distinguish them in the Photos app.

[image]

Is there any way to know witch pic is from cloud and with one is local?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can know that by going into **file information** of that image, under it, there would be details like file-name,date,size, etc. and also source destination of file.

You simply cant distinguish by looking at it.

PS: Latest threshold build is 10586.338 with bug fixes, i suggest you to upgrade.

Comment: My phone is fully updated. And I can't find `file information` in the Photos app. Long tap bring Share, Add to album, Slideshow and Delete.

Comment: no, not from photo tiles, open the image, press ... and go to file information

Comment: it shows only file name without path.

Comment: go to file information of the image and swipe down, You''ll find storage pathin bottom-most row

Comment: There is a "Source" she it says it's in the device or OneDrive. Thanks.